# How can I hide a specific span class on a page with a dynamic ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a class called "details" on all single event pages but not on my main events page.

The main event page is `demosite.com/events/`
The single event pages are `demosite.com/events/?event_id=2`.

I've tried with css pseudo classes but can't get it to work. I'm trying this with javascript but it's not working - as it hides the "details" class on both pages.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
$(function(){
  var url = document.location.href;

  if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf('http://demosite.com/events/') >= 0) {
    $('.details').hide();
  } else {
    $('.details').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery please add the tag to your question.

Comment: shouldn't you be checking if the URL contains `event_id=` instead? Seems to me that it will always contain `http://demosite.com/events/` but the query string parameter would be optional...

Comment: Your current version matches both pages. Add `?event_id=` to the string argument to `indexOf()` as in `.indexOf('http://demosite.com/events/?event_id=')`.

Comment: Thank you ochi and juan.facorro! That's exactly what I needed. My logic was backwards. The argument corrected to your suggestion worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* of the pages will include `demosite.com/events` - you're looking for pages that don't also have `event_id`s.

```
if (document.location.search.indexOf('event_id=') >= 0))
  $('.details').hide();
} else {
  $('.details').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is see if there is a parameter being passed to the url and then hide based on that.  So here is a javascript function to get the parameter and the check for it:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var eventid = getParamterByName('event_id');
    if ( eventid != "" ) {
       $('.details').hide();
    }
    else {
      $('.details').show();
    }

});

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


</script>
```